# Using Jenkins and email-ext. How can I add SVN_REVISION_1 to the email?

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I'm building a project with multiple SVN repositories. Using the Email-ext plugin to email when a job is successfull or failed.

When I use the token ${SVN_REVISION} all I get is the number 400, which isn't the build number nor any of the repositories' revision number.

What I want to use is the same variable the svn plugin provides: %SVN_REVISION_1%, but neither ${ENV, var="SVN_REVISION_1"} nor 
${ENV, var="%SVN_REVISION_1%"} work.

Also, when I list the variables (${ENV, var=""}) I can't find SVN_REVISION or SVN_REVISION_1.

The email needs to have SVN_REVISION_1 on the subject, or else it'll be quite a hassle to find what version was built.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${ENV, var="SVN_REVISION_1"}  does work. I was trying to force the email by aborting the build. If the build is aborted too soon, SVN_REVISION_1 is never created.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept your own answer

Answer (score 2):

I just tried using ${ENV, var="SVN_REVISION_1"} with our two modules we use on subversion and it worked. Thanks!